# Jenkins is not able to recognize xmlstarlet in my shell script

Tags: jenkins, xmlstarlet

I have Jenkins running on my local Windows 7 machine. I am trying to use Jenkins for Salesforce deployment and have added a shell script to parse `package.xml`. My script uses xmlstarlet to do the parsing, but when I build the project I am getting the following error:

```
./modifyPackage.bash: line 9: xml: command not found
./modifyPackage.bash: line 24: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am using the git sh.exe to execute the shell script, so I have added the below path in Shell executable.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

Looks to me that Jenkins is not able to recognize the xml starlet used in shell script. I also tried adding `xmlstarlet-1.6 exe` file in the GIT directory, but it didn't work. How should I fix this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem. I needed to add the path of `xml` starlet as a `PATH` environment variable in *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System* -> *Global Properties* with key as `PATH` and value as `$PATH:$Actual Path of xml starlet`.